# Bash script for monitoring a directory and symlinking all newly created subdirectories and their files

Tags: shell-script, symlink, inotify

I am in need of a bash script to recursively watch a folder and symlink every new file and  subdirectory to another folder.

this script correctly symlinks subdirectories and their contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -r -m '/source_dir' -e create -e moved_to |
    while read dir action file; do
 cp -as $dir/$file /destination_dir/$file
done
```

However, the problem is that if a file gets added to a sub directory, a symlink will be created directly in the destination directory instead of its respective subdirectory , how do I rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the directory path in the target destination

```
#!/bin/bash
#
src='/source_dir'
dst='/destination_dir'

inotifywait -r -m "$src" --format '%w%f' -e CREATE,MOVED_TO |
    while IFS= read -r item
    do
        # echo "Got $item"
        if [[ ! -d "$item" ]]
        then
            echo mkdir -p "${item%/*}"
            echo cp -as "$item" "$dst/${item#$src/}"
        fi
    done
```

Remove the two `echo` prefixes when you're happy it's doing what you expect. Uncomment the `echo "Got $item"` to see some of what's going on.

Please note that it is not possible to use `inotifywait` in this manner to handle file or directory names that contain newlines (adding `\000` or even `\001` to the `--format` string, with or without `$'...'` seems to prevent `inotifywait` from delivering any status updates at all).

Comment: I get cannot stat "/filename" as if I didn't specify the full path to the file when trying to use this.

Comment: There's no `filename` in my example. Since your original had paths modified, and I've used those here, please convert your failure message back to something that matches here too

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding you correctly or if am not explaining myself well, I literally just get "cp: cannot stat '/file_that_should've_been_symlinked' " as an error message.

Comment: You can't have done unless you've already removed the `echo` statements. In which case, put them back until you're happy it's doing what you expect

Comment: I did remove them. This is what echo prints out: mkdir -p /destination_dir  cp -as /filename /destination_dir/filename

Comment: I suggest `inotifywait ... --format "%w%f" | while read -r fullpath; do ...` and into there we only want to use this fullpath. Also this way it seems protected from whitespaces.

Comment: @thanasisp you are absolutely correct. I should have done that in the first place - thank you for the reminder

Comment: @user5672 I have rewritten the loop to be more robust. Please try again now

Comment: Yes, it works now. Thank you very much!